# How to hit a function when scroll position is reaches the top position?

Tags: javascript, angular

When scroll position hit the top position of the document the function is called. How to do that?

Comment: what did you tried so far? please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Good way to do it is to use the HostListener

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
    let scroll = this.window.pageYOffset || this.document.documentElement.scrollTop || this.document.body.scrollTop || 0;
    if (number = 0) {
      // Do some stuff here
    }
}
```

Now I just wanna add that you probably need to account for elastic scroll on mac desktops. Meaning that your scroll position can go in minus, and might not hit 0 exactly when you want this event to fire.

Here is a good [blog post](https://brianflove.com/2016/10/10/angular-2-window-scroll-event-using-hostlistener/) about this, if you want more reading material

Answer (score 0):

Use addEventListener on body, and listen for 'scroll' event, then when event is fired check scrollY property of window, and if it is 0, then you are on top.

```
function yourFunction() {
  console.log('you are on top');
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.scrollY == 0) yourFunction();
}, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use HostListener to listen to the scroll event

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
onWindowScroll() {
 // get scroll postion 
  let number = this.window.pageYOffset || 
  this.document.documentElement.scrollTop || this.document.body.scrollTop || 
  0;

 // here you can check the scroll postion
  if (number > 100) {

  } 
}
```